Difference in circuit simulation LTSpice vs TINA TI
I was simulating a circuit using LTspice and TINA TI. The only difference is that in the LTspice simulation I am using Analog devices parts and in TINA TI simulation equivalent TI parts are used. This is a PI controller circuit.
In LTspice I am getting the required output but in TINA TI it is not working as expected because the capacitor C1 (Present in the TINA Schematic) is blocking the DC path.
May I know why the circuit is working in LTspice and not working in TINA TI.
Circuit Diagram LTspice

RESULT:LTspice

Circuit Diagram:TINA TI

Result:TINA TI

Below image shows the input-output waveform when TI spice models are imported to Ltspice.

Below is Input output with AD parts.

I can see that both are going to expected output but for TI parts there is a peaking initially.

If you delay everything so that all start-up behavior is over, does the difference go away?

Have you tried using the TI parts in LTspice? TI supplies a PSpice compatible model on their web site

Updtaed the question

In your TINA-TI schematic, it looks like V7 (your positive supply for U3) is backwards.  You should flip it around to correct it and make it consistent with how you drafted your other opamp supplies.

